# How to solve lighting scene problem?

Tags: materials, lighting, scene, filmic-blender

My [Blender Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mm8jwdfumpw3kun/THIS.blend?dl=0)

I am trying to make some product scene - but I cannot figure out the light. Output format should be - plastic bottle should be little glossy and reflective (same wrap material), PNG transparent file, it should cast a low shadow on ground but still look realistic .

Render
[image]

Photo should look like this
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Please pack your images before sharing your file, and show an image of your own scene

Comment: thanks but I meant please show a render of your current scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count on an HDRI as light source, choose a studio image, increase the *Background*'s *Strength* (here, 12, but it can be more, or less, and you can add some lights). For the floor use a *Diffuse* node instead of an *Emission*, you need a shadow beneath the objects. Result:

[image]

The HDRI I've used (check the Polyhaven website for free HDRIs):

[image]

Comment: Thats great! Can you provide me the blend file so I can save up some time?

Comment: sure, file here: https://workupload.com/file/mCbBn7b99XE